# Import MouseEvent from @agm/core is not working in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular

In my Angular 9 Application I am using agm google map every thing is working find but when i import MouseEvent it shows an error (`src/app/place/place.component.ts:3:9 - error TS2305: Module '"../../../../../../Projects/Angular/mean2020/node_modules/@agm/core/agm-core"' has no exported member 'MouseEvent'.`) i google it but did not find any proper solutions any body help thanks in advance

this is may ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';
import { MouseEvent } from '@agm/core';

   markerDragEnd($event: MouseEvent) {
        console.log($event);
        this.latitude = $event.coords.lat;
        this.longitude = $event.coords.lng;
        this.getAddress(this.latitude, this.longitude);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`MouseEvent` does not come from `@agm/core` since new 3.0.0-beta version, but from the google maps script.

Try installing the types package

```
npm install --save @types/googlemaps
```

and use it like:

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef,
  NgZone
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  MapsAPILoader
} from '@agm/core';

markerDragEnd($event: google.maps.MouseEvent) {
  console.log($event);
  this.latitude = $event.coords.lat;
  this.longitude = $event.coords.lng;
  this.getAddress(this.latitude, this.longitude);
}
```

Your `tsconfig` should also be updated to include:

```
"types": [
      "googlemaps"
]
```

This is caused since latest version from agm ([refer to their changelog](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md))

Comment: i have already installed this but it not works 
but when i changed the agm/core version to 1.1.0 in package.json file and it works

Comment: It's because the latest version of agm/core they have removed the export of their own MouseEvent and now use the google.maps one.
Check you `tsconfig`, it should include `googlemaps` into `types`

Comment: i did all these things but not work only need to change @agm/core version in pacakge.json

Comment: Yeah it doesnt work for me either, added googlemaps type to all my tsconfigs as well as installed the library

Comment: `"@types/googlemaps": "3.39.12"` with this version it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

as mentioned before `MouseEvent` does not come from @agm/core since new
3.0.0-beta version, but from the google maps script.

and you have to add to your tsconfig

```
"types": [
      "googlemaps"
]
```

However this interface has no property called `coord` instead it has `latLng` which has two functions, `lat` and `lng`
so instead of using

```
this.latitude = $event.coords.lat;
this.longitude = $event.coords.lng;
```

your code should be this:

```
markerDragEnd($event: google.maps.MouseEvent) {
  console.log($event);
  this.latitude = $event.latLng.lat();
  this.longitude = $event.latLng.lng();
  this.getAddress(this.latitude, this.longitude);
}
```

Tried out myself since i was having the same issue, hope it's useful.